# How to draw lines in different colors?

Tags: android, android-layout, color-picker

I have developed an application which draws lines on the screen .I want to use different colors for the lines but all the lines are appearing in same color.

I have a color picker in my code to change the colors and i want to draw lines of different colors each time by selecting colors, but as of now since i am constructing lines and rendering it.When i choose initially red and draw a line, and then later select blue and draw a line , now the older line is also getting changed to blue instead of red, However i want the red to remain as red, and blue as such can any one help?

My code is given below

**MyDemo.java:**

```
public class MyDemo extends Activity implements
        ColorPickerDialog.OnColorChangedListener {

    private LinearLayout root;

    private Button btnReset;
    private Button btnPickColor;
    public static int selectedColor = Color.BLACK;
    MyImageView view;
    private static final String COLOR_PREFERENCE_KEY = "color";



    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_my_demo);

        root = (LinearLayout) findViewById(R.id.root);
        btnReset = (Button) findViewById(R.id.reset);
        btnPickColor = (Button) findViewById(R.id.pickColor);

        final MyImageView view = new MyImageView(this);
        view.setLayoutParams(new LinearLayout.LayoutParams(
                LinearLayout.LayoutParams.FILL_PARENT,
                LinearLayout.LayoutParams.FILL_PARENT));
        root.addView(view);

        btnReset.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            public void onClick(View v) {
                view.reset();
            }
        });

        btnPickColor.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            public void onClick(View v) {
                // color picker class call
                int color = PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(
                        MyDemo.this).getInt(COLOR_PREFERENCE_KEY, Color.WHITE);
                new ColorPickerDialog(MyDemo.this, MyDemo.this, color).show();

            }
        });
    }

    public void colorChanged(int color) {
        PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(this).edit()
                .putInt(COLOR_PREFERENCE_KEY, color).commit();
        selectedColor = color;
    }


}
```

**MyImageView.java:**

```
public class MyImageView extends ImageView implements View.OnTouchListener {

    private int id = -1;
    private Path path;
    private List<Path> paths = new ArrayList<Path>();
    private List<PointF> points = new ArrayList<PointF>();
    boolean multiTouch = false;
    MyDemo demo;

    public MyImageView(Context context) {
        super(context);
        this.setOnTouchListener(this);
        Log.d("Constructor", " Control in constructor");
    }

    public void reset() {
        paths.clear();
        points.clear();
        path = null;
        id = -1;
        invalidate();
    }

    @Override
    protected void onDraw(Canvas canvas) {
        super.onDraw(canvas);
        int colorPicked = MyDemo.selectedColor;
        if (colorPicked != Color.BLACK) {
            Paint paint = createPen(colorPicked);
            paint.setStyle(Paint.Style.STROKE);
            for (Path path : paths) {
                canvas.drawPath(path, paint);
            }
            for (int i = 0; i < points.size(); i++) {
                PointF p = points.get(i);
                canvas.drawText("" + p.x, p.y, i, createPen(colorPicked));
            }
        } else {
            Paint paint = createPen(colorPicked);
            paint.setStyle(Paint.Style.STROKE);
            for (Path path : paths) {
                canvas.drawPath(path, paint);
            }}
            for (int i = 0; i < points.size(); i++) {
                PointF p = points.get(i);
                canvas.drawText("" + p.x, p.y, i, createPen(colorPicked));
            }
        }


    private PointF copy(PointF p) {
        PointF copy = new PointF();
        copy.set(p);
        return copy;
    }

    public boolean onTouch(View v, MotionEvent event) {
        int action = event.getAction();
        switch (action & MotionEvent.ACTION_MASK) {
        case MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN:
            multiTouch = false;

            id = event.getPointerId(0);
            PointF p = getPoint(event, id);
            path = new Path();
            path.moveTo(p.x, p.y);
            paths.add(path);
            points.add(copy(p));
            break;
        case MotionEvent.ACTION_POINTER_DOWN:
            multiTouch = true;
            for (int i = 0; i < event.getPointerCount(); i++) {
                int tId = event.getPointerId(i);
                if (tId != id) {
                    points.add(getPoint(event, i));
                }
            }
            break;
        case MotionEvent.ACTION_MOVE:
            if (!multiTouch) {
                p = getPoint(event, id);
                path.lineTo(p.x, p.y);
            }
            break;
        }
        invalidate();
        return true;
    }

    private PointF getPoint(MotionEvent event, int i) {
        int index = 0;
        return new PointF(event.getX(index), event.getY(index));
    }

    public Paint createPen(int color) {
        Paint pen = new Paint();
        pen.setColor(color);
        float width = 3;
        pen.setStrokeWidth(width);
        return pen;
    }

}
```

**ColorPickerDialog.java:**

```
public class ColorPickerDialog extends Dialog {

    public interface OnColorChangedListener {
        void colorChanged(int color);

    }

    private final OnColorChangedListener mListener;
    private final int mInitialColor;

    private static class ColorPickerView extends View {
        private final Paint mPaint;
        private final Paint mCenterPaint;
        private final int[] mColors;
        private final OnColorChangedListener mListener;

        ColorPickerView(Context c, OnColorChangedListener l, int color) {
            super(c);
            mListener = l;
            mColors = new int[] { 0xFFFF0000, 0xFFFF00FF, 0xFF0000FF,
                    0xFF00FFFF, 0xFF00FF00, 0xFFFFFF00, 0xFFFF0000 };
            Shader s = new SweepGradient(0, 0, mColors, null);

            mPaint = new Paint(Paint.ANTI_ALIAS_FLAG);
            mPaint.setShader(s);
            mPaint.setStyle(Paint.Style.STROKE);
            mPaint.setStrokeWidth(32);

            mCenterPaint = new Paint(Paint.ANTI_ALIAS_FLAG);
            mCenterPaint.setColor(color);
            mCenterPaint.setStrokeWidth(5);
        }

        private boolean mTrackingCenter;
        private boolean mHighlightCenter;

        @Override
        protected void onDraw(Canvas canvas) {
            float r = CENTER_X - mPaint.getStrokeWidth() * 0.5f;

            canvas.translate(CENTER_X, CENTER_X);

            canvas.drawOval(new RectF(-r, -r, r, r), mPaint);
            canvas.drawCircle(0, 0, CENTER_RADIUS, mCenterPaint);

            if (mTrackingCenter) {
                int c = mCenterPaint.getColor();
                mCenterPaint.setStyle(Paint.Style.STROKE);

                if (mHighlightCenter) {
                    mCenterPaint.setAlpha(0xFF);
                } else {
                    mCenterPaint.setAlpha(0x80);
                }
                canvas.drawCircle(0, 0, CENTER_RADIUS
                        + mCenterPaint.getStrokeWidth(), mCenterPaint);

                mCenterPaint.setStyle(Paint.Style.FILL);
                mCenterPaint.setColor(c);
            }
        }

        @Override
        protected void onMeasure(int widthMeasureSpec, int heightMeasureSpec) {
            setMeasuredDimension(CENTER_X * 2, CENTER_Y * 2);
        }

        private static final int CENTER_X = 100;
        private static final int CENTER_Y = 100;
        private static final int CENTER_RADIUS = 32;

        private int ave(int s, int d, float p) {
            return s + java.lang.Math.round(p * (d - s));
        }

        private int interpColor(int colors[], float unit) {
            if (unit <= 0)
                return colors[0];
            if (unit >= 1)
                return colors[colors.length - 1];

            float p = unit * (colors.length - 1);
            int i = (int) p;
            p -= i;

            // now p is just the fractional part [0...1) and i is the index
            int c0 = colors[i];
            int c1 = colors[i + 1];
            int a = ave(Color.alpha(c0), Color.alpha(c1), p);
            int r = ave(Color.red(c0), Color.red(c1), p);
            int g = ave(Color.green(c0), Color.green(c1), p);
            int b = ave(Color.blue(c0), Color.blue(c1), p);

            return Color.argb(a, r, g, b);
        }

        private static final float PI = 3.1415926f;

        @Override
        public boolean onTouchEvent(MotionEvent event) {
            float x = event.getX() - CENTER_X;
            float y = event.getY() - CENTER_Y;
            boolean inCenter = java.lang.Math.sqrt(x * x + y * y) <= CENTER_RADIUS;

            switch (event.getAction()) {
            case MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN:
                mTrackingCenter = inCenter;
                if (inCenter) {
                    mHighlightCenter = true;
                    invalidate();
                    break;
                }
            case MotionEvent.ACTION_MOVE:
                if (mTrackingCenter) {
                    if (mHighlightCenter != inCenter) {
                        mHighlightCenter = inCenter;
                        invalidate();
                    }
                } else {
                    float angle = (float) java.lang.Math.atan2(y, x);
                    // need to turn angle [-PI ... PI] into unit [0....1]
                    float unit = angle / (2 * PI);
                    if (unit < 0) {
                        unit += 1;
                    }
                    mCenterPaint.setColor(interpColor(mColors, unit));
                    invalidate();
                }
                break;
            case MotionEvent.ACTION_UP:
                if (mTrackingCenter) {
                    if (inCenter) {
                        mListener.colorChanged(mCenterPaint.getColor());

                    }
                    mTrackingCenter = false; // so we draw w/o halo
                    invalidate();
                }
                break;
            }
            return true;
        }
    }

    public ColorPickerDialog(Context context, OnColorChangedListener listener,
            int initialColor) {
        super(context);

        mListener = listener;
        mInitialColor = initialColor;
    }

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        OnColorChangedListener l = new OnColorChangedListener() {
            public void colorChanged(int color) {
                mListener.colorChanged(color);
                dismiss();
            }
        };

        LinearLayout layout = new LinearLayout(getContext());
        layout.setOrientation(LinearLayout.VERTICAL);
        layout.setGravity(Gravity.CENTER);
        layout.setPadding(10, 10, 10, 10);
        layout.addView(new ColorPickerView(getContext(), l, mInitialColor),
                new LinearLayout.LayoutParams(
                        LinearLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT,
                        LinearLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT));
        setContentView(layout);
        setTitle("Pick a Color");
    }
}
```

Comment: anyone knows then suggest me some sites for reference...

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure but it seams a problem is in your onDraw method

```
Paint paint = createPen(colorPicked);
paint.setStyle(Paint.Style.STROKE);
for (Path path : paths) {
    canvas.drawPath(path, paint);
}
```

You select a color first (it's the last color you picked) and then with a same color you draw each path.
I think that the solution for this could be to create array of colors which will contain color for every path you create and to pick corresponding color before you draw each path

Answer (score 0):

try this, it will help you

```
  @Override
  protected void onDraw(Canvas canvas) {

    canvas.drawBitmap(mBitmap, 0, 0, mBitmapPaint);
    int colorPicked = MainActivity.selectedColor;

    paint1 = createPen(colorPicked);
     for (Path p : paths){       
         canvas.drawPath(p, paint1);
         paint1.setColor(colorPicked);
     }

}

private Paint createPen(int color) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub

    paint1 = new Paint();
    paint1.setAntiAlias(true);
    paint1.setDither(true);
    paint1.setStyle(Paint.Style.STROKE);
    paint1.setStrokeJoin(Paint.Join.ROUND);
    paint1.setStrokeCap(Paint.Cap.ROUND);
    paint1.setStrokeWidth(3);
    return paint1;
}
```