# How to Draw line Graph having different colors in Single Line

Tags: java, android, graph, android-canvas, achartengine

I want to Make the Line Graph like Below Image :

[image]

I've had a look at some `Stackoverflow questions` such as [How to Draw Line with Using Canvas](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3616676/how-to-draw-a-line-in-android), [How To Draw Lines With Different Colors](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12455554/how-to-draw-lines-in-different-colors) and so on. But I haven't been able to figure it how to do it myself.

**Question :** 
I have an idea about what I could make with the `AChartEngine Line Chart Graph`. I'm not sure, how possible is it to create a line graph with the  `AChartEngine`?

What are the alternatives to achieve the same result?

Any help would be highly appreciated.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/424752/any-good-graphing-packages-for-android

Comment: I can't help with changing colours over the x-axis but I suggest using Anders Ericsson's (Jayway) chart as a starting point rather than ACE for this kind of chart. Blog and Code can be found here: http://www.jayway.com/2012/08/29/creating-custom-android-views-part-3-animating-your-custom-views-smoothly/

Answer (score 2):

That is not difficult, you need to create a radial gradient paint with the center in the middle of the curve. Then in colors[] you add as many colors as you want. For **positions** you can set to **null**, then the colors will be evenly distributed.

```
myPaint.setShader(new RadialGradient( 
    float x, float y, 
    float radius, 
    int[] colors, 
    float[] positions,
    Shader.TileMode tile));
```

Also you should apply this only when the path is formed; you will need to get path bounds with

```
RectF bounds = new RectF();
myPath.computeBounds(bounds, true);
```

Now you can easily find center and radius.

Answer (score 0):

You can add several series of data, each one having a separate color.